# Facebook share images and description

Tags: facebook, share

Why this link work to share:
[share with appId: 567505730081965](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?&app_id=567505730081965&href=http%3A%2F%2Fthathrowdown.com%2F%23%2Fmusic%2F595%2FRIKI%20-WOMAN%20OF%20LIFE&description=RIKI%20-WOMAN%20OF%20LIFE&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fthathrowdown.com%2Fimages%2FRIKId6gvGjmFRmZUoSGXqF7f.jpg)
but this not:
[share with appId: 462951467373369](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?&app_id=462951467373369&href=http%3A%2F%2Fthathrowdown.com%2F%23%2Fmusic%2F595%2FRIKI%20-WOMAN%20OF%20LIFE&description=RIKI%20-WOMAN%20OF%20LIFE&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fthathrowdown.com%2Fimages%2FRIKId6gvGjmFRmZUoSGXqF7f.jpg)

its same url except the appId.

Comment: Presumably because the second app uses API v2.9, in which this was removed. It will be removed for all other API versions as well soon. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations

Comment: Is there a place where i can change that to use old API till i fix the share?

Comment: Not if you created the app after v2.9 was introduced. App dashboard shows which is the lowest API version your app can use.

Comment: Do i need also to have publish_actions approved to be able to post with new appId?

Comment: No, the dialogs don’t require any permissions.